# EF Core: Make reference object readonly but still includable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have following class:

```
public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make the reference navigation property readonly to make sure that the dependent entity cannot be changed through the principal entity.

I tried it like this:

```
public Blog Blog { get; }
```

But then I get the following error when it tries to execute an `Include`:
**"The expression '[post].Blog' passed to the Include operator could not be bound."**

How do I make the reference navigation property readonly but still includable?

Answer (score 0):

If the model class is in the same assembly and namespace as the EF context, and other usages are not, you can try making `Blog`'s setter `internal`, which will allow EF to set it but prevent attempts from elsewhere. You may also have to adjust your AssemblyInfo file for the project to make internals visible to the EntityFramework DLL and namespaces, as the code actually doing the setting will be there.

Keep in mind that while this will prevent other coders setting `Blog` to a new instance of a Blog type, the existing instance will still be mutable, so coders/users can update the data members without changing the reference stored in the `Post`. You can lock down the setters in Blog by internalizing them similarly to the Blog property on Post, but you start opening a can of worms regarding how to make intentional changes to a Blog; if all Blogs are always read-only except at the DAL, then the only way to change a Blog is to expose a method in your DAL that takes some mutable variant of a Blog like a BlogDto, and copies the specified parameters over to the Blog object. If that's what you want, great, but it probably isn't, whether you know that yet or not.